# IPython interactive running using imported module

Tags: python, ipython

I have a module as follows:

module1.py

```
Class bla():
  code here

def main():

  g1=bla()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

When I do `ipython module1.py` or go into IPython and `import module1` the code runs as expected. However, when I then type something like `print g1` it says that `g1` is not defined, even though I defined `g1` in the main program. It seems that the code runs the main program and then "exits" it somehow and just leaves me with the ipython prompt. I want to use the variables that I defined in the main function...

How do I do this?

Comment: Martijn Pieters's answer to this question will make more sense if you have an understanding of how "scope" works in python. Here is a pretty decent introduction to how it works: http://beastie.cs.ua.edu/cs150/book/index_13.html

Answer (score 3):

You would have to mark `g1` as a global:

```
def main():
    global g1
    g1 = bla()
```

Normally, any name defined in a function is local to the function only. You'd still have to *import* the name from the module, or refer to it as an attribute of the module:

```
import module1

print module1.g1
```